# Spring RouterFunction endpoint with coroutines coRouter return 404

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I have a code

```
@Configuration
class RouteConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun apiRouter(handler: UserHandler): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
        return router {
            "/api".nest {
                GET("/users") { ok().bodyValue(handler.getAllUsers()) }
                GET("/users/{id}") {
                    val user: User? = handler.getUserById(it.pathVariable("id").toInt())
                    if (user != null) {
                        ok().bodyValue(user)
                    } else {
                        ok().build()
                    }
                }
                POST("/users") {
                    ok().bodyValue(handler.createUser(it.bodyToMono(User::class.java).block()))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this code works fine.
[image]

So i want use coroutines inside handling functions:

```
@Configuration
class RouteConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun apiRouter(handler: UserHandler): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
        return coRouter {
            "/api".nest {
                GET("/users") { ok().bodyAndAwait(handler.getAllUsers()) }
                GET("/users/{id}") {
                    val user: User? = handler.getUserById(it.pathVariable("id").toInt())
                    if (user != null) {
                        ok().bodyValueAndAwait(user)
                    } else {
                        ok().buildAndAwait()
                    }
                }
                POST("/users") {
                    ok().bodyValueAndAwait(handler.createUser(it.bodyToMono(User::class.java).awaitSingle()))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So after i change router *RouterFunctionDsl* to coRouter **CoRouterFunctionDsl** my endpoints start return 404 NOT FOUND and IDEAD also can't find these endpoints.
[image]

What should i do to set up coRouter in a correct way.

Comment: I tried a stripped down version of your example, and it worked just fine. Maybe you can provide a complete example project on GitHub?

Here's my working example:
https://pastebin.com/vqVP1mHa

Comment: I have found my mistake. I checked  it in @WebFluxTest test class and i had forgotten  to  add @ContextConfiguration(classes = [RouteConfiguration::class]) annotation to get routes in context. But in intellij Idea tool i don't have this controllers even if they work fine in runtime.